# Gerrit Trigger lost connection due to com.jcraft.jsch.JSchAlgoNegoFailException

Tags: jenkins, jsch, gerrit-trigger

The Gerrit Trigger plugin worked well previously, but from a time point that I couldn't figure out, the connection can never be established with following error message:

```
Connection error : com.jcraft.jsch.JSchAlgoNegoFailException: Algorithm negotiation fail: algorithmName="server_host_key" jschProposal="ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256" serverProposal="ssh-rsa"
```

Gerrit Trigger version: 2.39.0

SSH key was generated via ssh-keygen

I noticed there is a plugin named JSch dependency, versioned at 0.2.8-65.v052c39de79b_2, which is the latest one.

I've checked answers in stackoverflow for a while, but didn't find any useful info. Could you please help?

Comment: Either use a more secure server or configure jsch as explained on https://github.com/mwiede/jsch#why-do-ssh-rsa-type-keys-not-work-with-this-jsch-fork-and-my-server

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following JVM_OPTS at the start of jenkins: -Djsch.client_pubkey=ssh-rsa,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256 -Djsch.server_host_key=ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa

from: https://github.com/jenkinsci/publish-over-ssh-plugin/issues/312